# Bash script to replace info in file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a new file that I created that has a list of all directories that have a particular file:

```
$ find . -name "bun.biscuts" > TREE.temp
```

This writes all of the correct info I need to the new temp file.
I am having trouble writing a bash script using `sed` to replace emails in the `TREE.temp` file.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

echo Start!

for bun.biscuts in (TREE.temp)
do
    sed -i 's/EMAIL1/EMAIL2/g';
done
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: You could try this one-liner: `find . -name "bun.biscuts" -exec sed -i 's/EMAIL1/EMAIL2/g' {} \;`. Don't really need a temp file for this, it will actually make the task more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually need the temp file as a training piece, how would that change your answer?  This is really helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gniourf_gniourf's comment is right; you don't *need* to use a temporary file and loop to do this. But if you *want* to, you could do it like this:

```
while read; do
    sed -i 's/EMAIL1/EMAIL2/g' "$REPLY"
done < TREE.temp
```

which performs the `sed` operation on the filename on each line of the file. `$REPLY` is the default variable name that each line is written to by `read`. You can change the variable name by doing `read var` instead - then each line will be written to `$var`.

Comment: Thank you this worked as I needed, all of the answers were great

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/EMAIL1/EMAIL2/g' TREE.temp
```

Comment: what is the .bak piece?  That is new to me, also I have only been in this programming environment for 48 hours lol.

Comment: `-i.bak` option create a backup file named `TREE.temp.bak`. You can read `man sed` for more details.

Comment: `TREE.temp` contains the list of filenames, so this will perform the substitution on those names, it will not go to each file and perform the substitution there (which I think is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

If you have node on the computer you can `npm install -g rexreplace` and then

```
rexreplace 'email1' 'email2' TREE.tmp
```